# How can I insert an image on a Gtk.Label. Is this possible? Or do I need to find another solution?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I have a Database with this fields: Firstname, Lastname, picture.
I have a gtk.Label named infoLabel.

I would like to update the label a way like this:

```
Label.set_markup("<img src='pix/1.png'>\nName" + Firstname + " " + Lastname)
```

But it isn't works, because img isn't allowed in Pango markup. How I can do this?

Comment: Your proposed update doesn't include an image, which is kind of confusing.

Comment: Yeah, Stackoverlfow hide it. I remove the < and > characters now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't expect to be able to have an image in label, no.

But you should be able to replace any label with a container holding a GtkImage and the label, and solve it that way.

Of course you will have to have the image in local memory, first.

Comment: okay, so I need to figure out how can I do this. :) Thanks. Any sampla code? :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a "Home" label.

```
label_with_icon = gtk.HBox()
icon = gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_HOME, gtk.ICON_SIZE_MENU)
label_with_icon.pack_start(icon)
label_with_icon.pack_start(gtk.Label('Home'))
label_with_icon.show_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on John La Rooy's answer, but I had to make some adjustments. Don't know why, maybe due to a different version of the library or something.

```
label_with_icon = gtk.HBox()
icon = Gtk.Image.new_from_file("/path/to/file.png") # not .image_new_from_file
label_with_icon.pack_start(icon, False, False, 0)   # this method takes five args
label_with_icon.pack_start(gtk.Label('a caption'))
label_with_icon.show_all()
```